# How to open a case with the Premier Support Number?

Tags: administration, support, help

I have found a my premier suppor number for my org.

How do I open it/ attach it with the ticket case (so  I can get support quicker)

I have been told it is quicker as its a paid service we have.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this salesforce support link
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000001000&type=1

Comment: Please include the relevant information from the help topic in the answer itself. Should the link ever become invalid, this answer will become useless. Please read [answer] for more information, and then [edit] your post.